# Javascript Syntax getElementById outerHTML

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, outerhtml

I have a question concerning the Syntax of outerHTML. It is also possible that I am thinking in the wrong direction.

My html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<label for="language">Choose a language:</label>
<select name="language" id="language" value="val1">
<option value="val1">English</option>
<option value="val2">German</option>
</select>
<p>You selected: <span id="language"></span></p> <!-- shall display either "English" or "German" -->
<p>You selected the following option: <span id="language"></span></p> <!-- shall display either "val1" or "val2" -->
<script  src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am referring to a script where for the moment the only content is

```
var selectedlang = document.getElementById("language").outerHTML;
```

Within the html file it shall show the value and variable for it. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You can't have more than one element in a document with the same `id` value (the above has three). If you do it anyway, it's an invalid document and in theory the browser can do anything it wants (including ignoring the `id` entirely). In practice what they do is have `getElementById` give you the *first* element in the document with that `id`. They don't completely ignore the `id` on later elements, they just give the first one priority. But don't rely on it. Use some other means of identifying the elements if you have more than one.

Comment: Hi, yes, it is a syntax problem in the first place. How do I refer to the ID in order to put the variable or the value between the span elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one element in a document with the same `id` value; your current markup uses `id="language"` on three different elements. You'll need to change two of them at least.

I think you're asking how to:

1. Show the currently-selected option's text and value in the two `span`s, and
2. How to update what you show if the user changes the selection.

If you just wanted the selected value, you could use the `value` property of the `select` element. But for both text *and* value, you'll want the `selectedIndex` property and the `options` collection:

```
function showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan) {
    const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    if (option) {
        textSpan.textContent = option.text;
        valueSpan.textContent = option.value;
    } else {
        // No option is selected
        textSpan.textContent = "";
        valueSpan.textContent = "";
    }
}
```

In that example, I've had it accept the `select` and `span`s as parameters to the function.

You'd call that function on page load, and then again whenever the `select`'s `input` event fired.

Here's an example:

```js
const select = document.getElementById("language-select");
const textSpan = document.getElementById("text-span");
const valueSpan = document.getElementById("value-span");

function showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan) {
    const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    if (option) {
        textSpan.textContent = option.text;
        valueSpan.textContent = option.value;
    } else {
        // No option is selected
        textSpan.textContent = "";
        valueSpan.textContent = "";
    }
}

// Show on page load
showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan);

// Hook the `input` event
select.addEventListener("input", () => {
    // Update the contents of the elements
    showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan);
});
```

```html
<label for="language">Choose a language:</label>
<select name="language" id="language-select" value="val1">
<option value="val1">English</option>
<option value="val2">German</option>
</select>
<p>You selected: <span id="text-span"></span></p> <!-- shall display either "English" or "German" -->
<p>You selected the following option: <span id="value-span"></span></p> <!-- shall display either "val1" or "val2" -->
<script  src="./script.js"></script>
```

(Note that I changed all three `id`s.)